# Jenkins - Getting 404 When Testing Connection to Remote Private Docker Registry

Tags: docker, jenkins

Have a Jenkins server up and running with `Docker plugin 1.2.0` installed.

Have a private Docker registry running on another host on the same network. The registry is actually running in a Docker container with port exposed.

From the host where Jenkins server is running, I am able to do `wget http://{docker-ip}:{docker-port}`, and a 200 okay index.html is returned.

In Jenkins UI, I am trying to Configure Clouds a Docker connection to my private registry where I am setting Docker Host URI as `tcp://{docker-ip}:{docker-port}` but, when I test this connection I get:

```
404 page not found
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: 404 page not found
```

The Docker Host URI field only accepts `tcp://` and `unix://` protocols and I am not sure what I am missing in order to be able to push images from a Jenkins build into my private Docker registry?

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want to reach behind `tcp://docker-ip:docker-port`, Are you sure  `docker-ip:docker-port` is a TCP service?

Comment: I want to push built images in jenkins into a private Docker registry. docker-ip:docker-port is just an obfuscated ip address and port where my docker registry is running. The Docker Host URI in my cloud connection is actually set to an ip address and port like `tcp://192.168.1.2:5000`

Comment: Actually, looking at the docker registry's logs, I can see more detail. The `Test Connection` gets 404 from the Docker registry probably because there is nothing being served in the registry at `/`?